# How to deploy django to a dedicated web server?

Tags: python, django, apache

This is the first time for me to work with Django (and Python at all) so i'm little confused when it comes to deploying my web site to a web server. I've done with local development so now it's time to put my web site to a production server.
I have dedicated server (Red Hat 4.4.4-13 OS) with Webuzo CPanel which says that i already have Python (v 2.7), Django (1.6.1) and Apache (2.4.4) installed.

Of course, i have root access, so i've logged into my server and tried to check if Django is installed, but this command

```
>>>import django
```

gave me this error:

```
importerror: No module named django.
```

*(although Webuzo Control Panel says that i have Django installed).*

After that, i've managed to install Django using pip. So, for now, i have Python and Django (1.6.2) installed.

My next step was to make a new Django project on production server just to check if that will work, so I've created new directory in my `public_html` folder and ran this commands there:

```
>>> django-admin.py startproject test
# python manage.py runserver
```

and django gave me this message:

```
Validating models...
0 errors found
February 26, 2014 - 00:15:48
Django version 1.6.2, using settings 'test.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Then i've tried to access that location through web browser but nothing has happened (in fact, i've only got web folder structure). *PS* i tried to change localhost to my server's IP adress and Port :80 but that gave me an error that port is already in use.

I have read official Django documentation that reffers to deploying web site to a server but i don't know if i should mess with mod_wsgi, mod_fcgi, mod_python and such things because, as i said, i already have python and django installed on my web server?

So, what should I do in order to run django on my web server?

**UPDATE**

OK, i've installed mod_wsgi and added this to my Apache (2.4.4) config:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/****/public_html/*mysite.com*/testing/testing/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/****/public_html/*mysite.com*

<Directory /home/****/public_html/*mysite.com*/testing>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

This is my folder structure:

```
/home/*****/public_html/mysite.rs:
----------------------------------testing:
-----------------------------------------manage.py
                                         testing: 
-------------------------------------------------__init__.py  settings.py  urls.py  wsgi.py
```

When i visit mysite.com still nothing happens (mysite.com/testing/ gives me forbidden). Am i doing something wrong?
I'm exhausted now so i'll try with Heroku tomorrow...

Comment: If you've read the documentation, you'll know that you should **never** use runserver in production, and that yes you'll need to use wsgi.

Comment: You need to do some more reading on the topic. mod_wsgi should be the easiest for you to setup if you're on dedicated machine (mod_wsgi isn't always possible to employ when using shared hosting)

Comment: Also, to access the page when serving with runserve (just as a proof of concept though, never in prod) you should specify the address to 0.0.0.0 to accept any connections: `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`. You probably got the problem with 80 being used due to another webserver using it. If it is available you need to be root (sudo) to assign it.

Comment: Thank you guys, you've pointed me to right direction. I've been confused with all those modules so the main question was if i need to install them or not. I've installed mod_wsgi now.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Chapter 16 of Tango with Django and/or official docs:

- http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/deploy.html
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/

However, you seem to be missing some real basics here, so you may want to consider a managed PaaS like Heroku so that you don't have to worry about scaling/maintaining the server until you are comfortable with the details. Here's documentation on how to deploy Django to Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django

You also should use a version control system, like Git and deploy the repo code to the target production host, as opposed to starting a fresh project on a production server.

There are many good books that cover Django end to end. Suggest you search: https://www.google.com/search?q=python+django+book.

Comment: Please don't recommend the Django Book: it is outdated, and there's ah warning on the contents page saying not to use it.

Comment: great call, sorry. removed the reference and linked to official docs.

Answer (score 0):

Once django is installed using Webuzo, the necessary files are located here:
Base Path   /usr/local/apps/python2
Binary  /usr/local/apps/python2/bin/django-admin.py

You can locate other files accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As part of [a book I'm writing about TDD](http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/), I've written a couple of chapters which take you step-by-step through how to configure a web server, from scratch, to serve a Django web app.  It includes:

- setting up a user account and SSH keys
- installing nginx
- checking dns works
- creating a virtualenv
- setting up your database
- setting up static files
- installing gunicorn
- config for nginx virtualhost and gunicorn auto-start using upstarts

http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000754/ch08.html

And then the next chapter shows an example of how you can automated the whole thing using Fabric.

http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000754/ch09.html

There's a  fair bit of discussion of how this all relates to automated testing, but if you ignore those bits, it should hopefully be a good step-by-step guide to how to deploy a django app to a web server...